# How to know if a graph exists or not?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

Draw the required graph or explain why no such graph exists:
8-vertex, 2 component, simple graph with exactly 10 edges and three cycles.

- I think there is a graph but I'm not sure.
  Can anyone help to know the answer of this question?

Comment: Why do you think there is a graph? If you had found such a graph, you'd be sure, wouldn't you?

Comment: Have you studied "trees" recently? Do you know what a tree is, and the relationship between the number of vertices and the number of edges of a tree?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.** Assume that such a graph exists and see what you can figure out about it. Maybe you will arrive at a contradiction, proving that no such graph exists; failing that, knowing some conditions the graph has to satisfy will narrow down the search for an example.

**Hint.** There are exactly $8$ vertices, $10$ edges, and $3$ cycles. If you delete $3$ edges, one from each cycle, you will be left with a graph with $8$ vertices, $7$ edges, and no cycles. What do you know about a graph with $n$ vertices, $n-1$ edges, and no cycles? How many components can it have?